# Understanding a bourne shell script

Tags: php, shell, fastcgi, sh

I came across a wrapper script to run php as fastcgi, could someone explain what is going on in the script?

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/php5-cgi -c /etc/php5/cgi/php-fcgi.ini
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line (sha bang or hash bang) set the interpreter, in this case `/bin/sh` the standard shell, this is not necessarily a bourne shell.

The script is probably used to start a php-cgi session with a custom config file.

The -c flag is used to select a configuration file . .

try `/usr/bin/php5-cgi --help` for more information on available flags.

Comment: try `/usr/bin/php5-cgi --help` for more information that does not seem to work on the command line using wampserver.

Comment: ah, wamp .. I thought you were on a real OS. . 

Does the shell script actually work?

Comment: I figured I had to modify the location for it to work, but was not sure if that is what was supposed to do exactly

Answer (score 1):

Not much. It executes `/usr/bin/php5-cgi` with the parameter `-c /etc/php5/cgi/php-fcgi.ini`, i.e. it specifies a special configuration file.

Comment: ok I see I need to create a configuration file in apache for this

Answer (score 1):

The script replaces itself (`exec`), keeping the pid, by executing `usr/bin/php5-cgi -c /etc/php5/cgi/php-fcgi.ini`

If it did not use `exec`, whoever called it would not get the process ID of the php5-cgi process. Likely this script is intended as a drop-in replacement for executing php directly, and whatever uses this script needs the process ID of the php process.